# upload published application in another language on android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have already published english version of my android application. Now I want to upload spanish version of same app. How it can be achieve that both english and spanish app visible on market?
What changes i have to make in manifest file of both application?

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended. You should be able to have a fully translatable application with a single APK. (see the [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html))

That said, if you really need that, you'll have to publish 2 different APKs with 2 different package names.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a system for localization, while using only one APK. Essentially, you define all your Strings in strings.xml, and have a strings.xml for each language you want to support.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) for details.

Basically, you need to create a subfolder called `values-<two letter locale>` in your `/res` directory and fill it with the localized resources.

Beyond that, if you really really need to, you could change the package name and publish it as two separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use localized strings, change package name and you have two applications....

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to support multiple languages​​, you have to create a folder named values-(code of language), for example a case you should create a folder called "values​​-es" and put it into a file strings.xml with the same values ​​as the default folder but translated into Spanish. Those with the Spanish language set in their phone read this file, those without Spanish read values default folder in English. This is the recommender, but if you want to upload two apps you need to stablish a languaje requeriment whe you are in the upload menu of the google play store.